# How can I check if CSS calc() is available using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to check if [the CSS function `calc`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) is available using JavaScript?

I found lot of questions and articles about getting the same behaviour as `calc` using jQuery, but how can I only check if it's available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you can find the test as `css-calc` currently in the non-core detects. They use the following code:

```
Modernizr.addTest('csscalc', function() {
    var prop = 'width:';
    var value = 'calc(10px);';
    var el = document.createElement('div');

    el.style.cssText = prop + Modernizr._prefixes.join(value + prop);

    return !!el.style.length;
});
```

Comment: What does Modernizr._prefixes.join() do? A solution without Modernizr would need to replace this function.

Comment: @JoseGómez This lines tests appends all prefixes (`-webkit`, etc) to test, if there is any support and just the standard conform one. Hence, depending on the rest of your code, you can just drop that line.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late to the party but I figured I should share this because I was myself struggling with it. Came up with the idea of by using jQuery, I can create a div that uses the calc() value in a CSS property (such as width in this case) and also a fallback width in case the browser does not support calc(). Now to check whether it supports it or not, this is what I did:

Let's create the CSS style for the currently "non-existing" div element.

```
/* CSS3 calc() fallback */
#css3-calc {
    width: 10px;
    width: calc(10px + 10px);
    display: none;
}
```

Now, if the browser does not support calc(), the element would return a width value of 10. If it does support it, it would return with 20. Doesn't matter what the values are exactly, but as long as the two width properties have different values in the end (in this case 10 and 20).

Now for the actual script. It's pretty simple and I suppose it's possible with regular JavaScript too, but here's the jQuery script:

```
// CSS3 calc() fallback (for unsupported browsers)
$('body').append('<div id="css3-calc"></div>');
if( $('#css3-calc').width() == 10) {
    // Put fallback code here!
}
$('#css3-calc').remove(); // Remove the test element
```

---

Alternatively, native javascript check, and width:

`#css3-calc { width: 1px; width: calc(1px + 1px); }`

```
if( document.getElementById('css3-calc').clientWidth==1 ){
    // clientHeight if you need height
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I used this trick, but I used the width. That way I'm sure it doesnt mess up my page (0px height).

Comment: Made an edit, added the native JS variant, in which I used width. Also removed the `parseInt()` because `.width()` returns a number

Comment: This is a helpful answer but I think the native javascript thing should come first because people (like me) just don't read any further after seeing the `$` sign of jquery... also, +1. nice way to check.

Comment: with `display: none;`, wouldn't a JS engine measure 0 for its width?

Comment: `1px + 1px` is not needed, `calc(2px)` is still a calculation. Which leads me to my even more simple solution below...

Answer (score 2):

Calc detection was added to modernizer according to their news page.
http://modernizr.com/news/

> As well as tightening up support for existing tests, we've also added
> a number of new detects, many submitted by the community:
>
> ```
> [...]
> css-calc
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cssCheck = document.createElement("DIV");
cssCheck.style.marginLeft = "calc(1px)";
if (cssCheck.style.getPropertyValue("margin-left"))
{
    alert("calc is supported");
}
cssCheck = null;
```