# Check for CSS calc doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, calc

I searched for a way to detect whether a browser supports CSS calc and found this:
[How can I check if CSS calc() is available using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125415/how-can-i-check-if-css-calc-is-available-using-javascript)
I modified the solution of No. 5 as follows:

```
help = $('<img src="/images/buttonup.png">')
help.css({ width: "10px" });
help.css({ width: "calc(10px + 10px)" });
if (help.width() == 20) var calcSupport = true; else var calcSupport = false;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Chrome: help.width() returns 0 although Chrome supports calc obviously.
In Firefox it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome can't reliably provide computed styles of an element which hasn't been added to the DOM.

So you can append the element to the `body`, read its width, and remove it.

```js
var el = document.createElement('img');
el.style.width = "calc(10px + 10px)";
document.body.appendChild(el);
var calcSupport = getComputedStyle(el).width == '20px';
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

For really old browsers that don't support `getComputedStyle`, you can use jQuery `$(el).width() == 20`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks for noting that. `clientWidth` was not reliable, and it gave false negatives on Firefox. I have switched to `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: This is the solution: Adding the help element to the dom fixed the problem. Many thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

I think so this is what you are looking for..

HTML:

```
<img src="http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css3logo250.jpg" class='img'>
```

CSS:

```
.img{
   width: 100px;
   width: -webkit-calc(10px + 10px); 
   width:    -moz-calc(10px + 10px); 
   width:      -o-calc(10px + 10px);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var help = $(".img");
if(help.width() == 20){
   var calcSupport = true;
   alert('calc() is supported');
}else{
   var calcSupport = false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mew20h2/)

Answer (score 0):

Better use [`CSS.supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports):

```js
var calcSupport = CSS.supports("width", "calc(10px + 10px)");
```

Comment: Works only on a limited set of browsers.

Comment: @Nit Yes, but it's the proper way of doing it. And Chrome supports it, so it solves the problem. Of course, a dirty IE hack may be needed.

Comment: I would hardly call something that has no support at all on two common browsers _"the proper way"_.

Comment: @Nit `CSS.supports` is the cleaner way to test this, and it's standardized in [CSS Conditional Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/), which is a Candidate Recommendation. If some browsers don't support it, its their fault. As developers, we can provide a fallback code for those. But that doesn't mean the fallback code is better.

Comment: There's a large difference between candidate recommendation and reasonable to use. Above all, your code should work.

Comment: +1 for this solution. Although it might not be supported on all browsers, I don't see why somebody downvoted! Plus, browsers support only "popular" stuff - let's make it popular! :)